# AVPlayer on half-sphere instead of sphere for playing 180° video

Tags: ios, avplayer, scenekit, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

I'm trying to play 180 fisheye video with scenekit and one of the examples I found is using a sphere as AVPlayers geometry to play 360 degree video.

Problem is the video I'm using is captured with 180° fisheye camera and I need to represent it with a half sphere.

I've been fiddling with the code for 2 days but with no luck.

Since I'm not experienced in this subject, I've tried to put AVPlayer partially onto a full sphere or cut the SCNSphere in half without success.

The code below is for playing 360 video and from simple360player_iOS GitHub repo,

```
var screenScale : CGFloat                                       = 1.0
        if PROCESSOR_64BITS {
            screenScale                                                 = CGFloat(3.0)
        }

        player                                                          = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL!)
        let videoSpriteKitNodeLeft                                      = SKVideoNode(AVPlayer: player)
        let videoNodeLeft                                               = SCNNode()
        let spriteKitScene1                                             = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1280 * screenScale, height: 1280 * screenScale))
        spriteKitScene1.shouldRasterize                                 = true
        var spriteKitScenes                                             = [spriteKitScene1]

        videoNodeLeft.geometry                                          = SCNSphere(radius: 30)
        spriteKitScene1.scaleMode                                       = .AspectFit
        videoSpriteKitNodeLeft.position                                 = CGPoint(x: spriteKitScene1.size.width / 2.0, y: spriteKitScene1.size.height / 2.0)
        videoSpriteKitNodeLeft.size                                     = spriteKitScene1.size
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a partial sphere, partial mapping, or another object that otherwise achieves that goal is probably the most noble path. However, depending on the context of the project, in cases where you have 180 degree videos it is often quicker to double the width of the video and fill the additional space with black or something of your choosing. This is especially useful if there is a likelihood you'll have 360 video in the future.